# Can't connect Burrow to my amazon MSK cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka

I've tried several ways to connect the burrow application from my EC2 instance to my kafka cluster to get the consumer lag metrics. I can console produce and consume messages from the instance but the moment I want to connect burrow it throws this error in the logs.

```
"name":"kafkatestingcluster","error":"kafka: client has run out of available brokers to talk to (Is your cluster reachable?)"
```

I have checked the bootstrap servers twice, and the zookeeper as well and they are okay. I have also tried with cluster running versions 1.1.0 and 2.2.1, and different client versions in the burrow's config file.
Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 0):

Mind to share your configuration with us? did you enter the correct port?

Have you tried to run a simple telnet test from the host **Burrow runs in** to the Kafka brokers? Have you checked your inbound and outbound SG rules on AWS?
I would suggest testing those stuff first and if everything is good on that layer, switch Burrow [logging level](https://github.com/linkedin/Burrow/wiki/Configuration#logging) to `debug` and I'm sure it will give you a better understanding on what's going on.

Comment: @javier Soto were u able to get it working, I am also facing same issue. Not able to specify truststore location in Burrow which is required by MSK.